# cmidrule narrower

Tags: booktabs

[image]While we inserting `\cmidrule` width or color in tables second `\cmidrule` get narrower, please how to fix, please find MWE file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs,colortbl}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%\hangindent6pt
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\toprule
A & B &C &D &E\\
\arrayrulecolor{blue}\cmidrule[2pt]{2-3}\arrayrulecolor{red}\cmidrule[2pt]{4-5}%
A & B &C &D &E\\
A & B &C &D &E\\
A & B &C &D &E\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\toprule
A & B &C &D &E\\
\arrayrulecolor{blue}\cmidrule{2-3}\arrayrulecolor{red}\cmidrule{4-5}%
A & B &C &D &E\\
A & B &C &D &E\\
A & B &C &D &E\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\toprule
A & B &C &D &E\\
\cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}%
A & B &C &D &E\\
A & B &C &D &E\\
A & B &C &D &E\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is probably an digital artefact of your PDF browser and zoom level.

Comment: ...in other words, does the rule width seem to be similar when you zoom in?

Comment: ...and what PDF browser are you using? Adobe Reader?

Comment: In my tests colored `\cmidrule` aren't vertically aligned. their thickness and lengths are as declared. So I thing that issues is not at pdfviewers. As stated in  `colortbl` package documentation,  "colouring `\hline` and `\cline` is a bit more tricky ".

Comment: If I add \arrayrulecolor adding \cmidrule which affects next cmidrule slightly down. In my case we need to add different color for each cmidrule. Sorry for late response. I checked different PDF viewers all shown as not aligned cmidrule equally, please refer my attachment.